# Adding text directly to the control Text is destroying the content in the RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I'm making a small text editor as part of a larger application. So I've taken an `RichTextBox` and added an tool strip with some buttons. Actually everything works well with the editing part. My app requires the addition of a `DateTime` stamp in the textbox every time a button is clicked. When I do so, the entire markup is gone.

So what I do is:

```
 private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    richtextbox1.text += DateTime.Now.toString();
 }
```

Comment: anywhere else where you are working with richtextbox1.text?

Comment: Could you look at just updating your original post to clean up some of the spelling and gramma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> To read or set the text of a multiline text box, use the Lines property. **The Text property does not return any information about the formatting applied to the contents of the RichTextBox.** To get the rich text formatting (RTF) codes, use the Rtf property.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R) may help you.

This article shows how to extend a RichTextBox to allow append a string to its RTF property
The solution is like this :

```
public void InsertTextAsRtf(string _text, Font _font, 
    RtfColor _textColor, RtfColor _backColor) {

    StringBuilder _rtf = new StringBuilder();

    // Append the RTF header
    _rtf.Append(RTF_HEADER);

    // Create the font table from the font passed in and append it to the
    // RTF string
    _rtf.Append(GetFontTable(_font));

    // Create the color table from the colors passed in and append it to the
    // RTF string
    _rtf.Append(GetColorTable(_textColor, _backColor));

    // Create the document area from the text to be added as RTF and append
    // it to the RTF string.
    _rtf.Append(GetDocumentArea(_text, _font));

    this.SelectedRtf = _rtf.ToString();
  }
```

and

```
public void AppendTextAsRtf(string _text, Font _font, 
  RtfColor _textColor, RtfColor _backColor) {

  // Move carret to the end of the text
  this.Select(this.TextLength, 0);

  InsertTextAsRtf(_text, _font, _textColor, _backColor);
}
```